# How to subtract 4 months from today's date?

Tags: php, date, intervals, subtraction

I need to declare two dates in `"Ymd"` format: `$toDate` and `$fromDate`.

`$toDate` represents today's date and `$fromDate` needs to be 4 months earlier than today.

```
$toDate = Date('Ymd');
$fromDate = ?
```

How do I create `$fromDate`?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use the magic of [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/strtotime):

```
$fromDate = date("Ymd", strtotime("-4 months"));
```

Comment: today at 31st of december i tried the same code and tried to substract 1 month as mentioned above it returned me date of 1st december 2012. however i was expecting 30 november. is it expected result or its a bug?

Comment: @Mubashar I guess it's by design! Both approaches (yours and strtotime's) are arguably equally valid.

Answer (score 8):

see the code below...

```
$fourmonthsback = date("Ymd", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-4, date("d"),   date("Y")));
```

OR

```
$fourmonthsback = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-4, date("d"),   date("Y"));
```

Comment: This will not work in january, february, march or april as the month will be either 0 or negative.

Comment: @cypher - Actually mktime does date arithmetic. If you set the month parameter to anything less than 1 mktime will choose an earlier month.  If you set the month to 0 then mktime will modify the whole date to be December of the previous year.  This arithmetic works on all parameters of mktime except for the timezone.

Comment: Really? Sorry about that then, I didn't know that.