# Subtracting months from current date returns unexpected result

Tags: php, date

I just tried to subtract 6 and 5 months respectively from current date `08/29/2015 @ 11:19am (UTC)` and got the same result

Here is the code sample:

```
date("M, Y", strtotime("-5 months")) // returns Mar, 2015
date("M, Y", strtotime("-6 months")) // returns Mar, 2015
```

Is it due to day light saving? I think No.

Comment: Current Timestamp of my server is "1440847951"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
date("M, Y", strtotime("-6 months"))
```

Simply returns also `Mar, 2015` because there was no 29. February this year. So it takes the next month which is March.

To solve this just do it always from the first day of the month, e.g.

```
echo date("M, Y", strtotime("-6 months", strtotime(date('Y-m-01'))));
                                       //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ First day of month
```

Comment: Thanks @Rizier123. btw, PHP function `strtotime` should take the leap year into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only working option i could find for you. [How to subtract 4 months from today's date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163387/how-do-i-subtract-4-months-of-date-today)

```
echo date("Ymd", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-5, date("d"),   date("Y")));;
```

Comment: `echo date("Ymd", strtotime("-5 months"));` returns 20150329
and
`echo date("Ymd", strtotime("-6 months"));` returns 20150301
Both with third month

Comment: updated my answer. It really beats me. Weird problem