# PHP - subtracting today's year with an integer or string

Tags: php

I have the following columns in my table: *birth_year, birth_month, birth_day*

**example data from the table** is

```
birth_year         birth_month        birth_day
1996               April              1
```

**I only need to get the age of a user.**

It doesn't need to be accurate. *I just need to subtract the year today and his/her birth_year*

**example:**

his birth_year is 1996

and the date today is 2015

```
if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)
{
       $birth_day = $row['birth_year'];    //data from the database which equals to 1996
       $today = date("Y");                 //year today
       $age = $today - $birth_day;        //age of this user
        echo $age;                        //this should output 19
}
```

**My problem is** the `$age` variable from the above echoes a **blank or null** value.

here are the sources that might be similar to my question:

[source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163387/how-do-i-subtract-4-months-of-date-today) [source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521146/calculate-age-based-on-date-of-birth)

The difference between my question and those is that I can't follow the format of `DateTime` because my registration form looks like this.

[image]

Comment: You should not store date data in three separate columns in a database. All DBMS have dedicated types for that, like `datetime` or `timestamp`.

Comment: Instead of `echo`ing your variables, use `var_dump` so you can see it's type. You're probably using arithmetic with a string..

Comment: I used die($age) instead of echo, I thought it will give me the same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
$age = intval( $today ) - intval( $birth_day );
```

Also check if your mysql query returns what you expect (you did not provide it so it is hard to check).

Comment: your code outputs nothing, yes my query worked. i tried echoing it just now. and it gives me a value of 1996

Comment: Sorry I wrote it with capital but it should be intval without capital. Can you try again cause it should work.

Comment: It's still the same, sir.

Comment: I also tried echoing those 2 variables individually, both of them have values, but when i tried to subtract $today - $birth_year it returns nothing

Comment: I tried the suggested code, and it does indeed work.

Comment: How is that possible? I even tried to substitute $birth_year manually into a '1996' and 1996 but it still returns nothing

Comment: Turn on your error messages, perhaps something else in the code goes wrong.

Comment: Oh it works now, Im using die($age) a couple of times to see the output clearer, but i think it's the main reason why it gives me nothing

Comment: No problem. I advise you to add error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); so you see all errors happening.

Answer (score 0):

try this with the datetime:

```
if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run){
    $birth_day = $row['birth_year'];
    $bday = new DateTime($birth_day);
    $today = new DateTime(date("Y"));
    $age = $today->diff($bday);
    echo $age->y;
}
```